# Drawing different medium sketch

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing

I would like to draw the figure attached using Ti*k*Z-PGF package in LaTeX, do you have any advice or suggestion where I should start?

[image]

Comment: welcome to tex.se! what you try so far? where you stuck in your effort?

Comment: Have a look at some examples on [texample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/) for a starting point and maybe into the documentation of Ti*k*Z-PGF (use `\node`, `rectangle`, ...). Then make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you can get with that. Then you can ask for help with a *specific* problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE! The purpose of this site is to exchange codes and ask questions on codes, not to let others draw something for you. Since you are a newcomer, here is some code to give you a start.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[latex-latex,blue] (0,2) node[left]{$y$} -- (0,0) node[circle,draw,inner
sep=1.5pt]{} node[below left]{$z$} -- (2,0) node[below]{$x$};
\node[draw,blue,minimum width=7cm,minimum height=4cm] (box) at (7,2){};
\node[cyan,anchor=south] at (box.south) {water};
\draw[latex-latex] ([yshift=-3mm]box.south west) -- ([yshift=-3mm]box.south east)
node[midway,below] {length};
\draw[latex-latex] ([xshift=3mm]box.south east) -- ([xshift=3mm]box.north east)
node[midway,right] {height};
\draw[blue] ([yshift=5mm]box.west) -- ++ (-5mm,0) coordinate(aux1) |- ([yshift=-5mm]box.west)
coordinate[pos=0.5] (aux2);
\draw[latex-latex,red] ([xshift=-3mm]aux2) -- ([xshift=-3mm]aux1)
node[sloped,midway,above=2mm] {air diam};
\node[above left=1cm of aux1,anchor=south east,red] {Air};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is a so-called minimal working example, i.e. a compilable code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. I'd kindly like to ask you to append such MWEs to your future questions and answers.